# Как использовать существующий swagger.yaml для создания API документации?

Tags: django, api, swagger

Имеется готовый `swagger.yaml` возможно ли по нему воссоздать API документацию, например, на Джанге через `django-rest-swagger`. Как создать с нуля приблизительно понял, однако нет понятия об этом yaml'е, хочется просто адекватно его подцепить и с него все воссоздать. В моем понимании это как файл-конфиг, поправив который (заголовки, адреса, названия методов и т.д.) я подниму API, если некорректно составлен вопрос или не хватает информации, пожалуйста, напишите.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение с помощью библиотеки  `django-swagger-u`

[`https://github.com/assem-ch/django-swagger-ui`](https://github.com/assem-ch/django-swagger-ui)

Для быстрого старта просто копируете директорию из указанного репозитория, добавляете ее как приложение в `settings.py`, тут же добавляете переменную `SWAGGER_YAML_FILE`, в которой указывается путь на Ваш `swagger.yaml`. Затем в файле `urls.py` добавляете `path('', include('swagger_ui.urls')),`. Далее, по умолчанию, в разделе `/api-doc/` будет отрендеренная  yaml-страница.